# Constructing all finite irreps of SU(2), unitary or not

Tags: group-theory

When we construct representations of SU(2) in quantum mechanics, we're interested in finite, irreducible unitary representations. We had good reason to want unitary representations there. In other parts of physics, like when we talk about relating the Lorentz group to two copies of SU(2), it's less clear that we want unitary representations. My main question is: *do there exist finite dimensional representations of SU(2) that cannot be taken to a unitary representations via a similarity transformation?*

---

One of my thoughts on why we might be able to find finite-dimensional irreps that are not equivalent via a similarity transformation to the usual unitary irreps is that our usual derivations/constructions of the irreps use unitarity of the transformations in key ways.

For example, in introductory quantum texts like Griffiths's *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, unitarity is used in our discovery of said representations by enforcing that the generators of our finite, irrep are Hermitian.

This means that a finite irrep's $J_z$ is Hermitian and hence has a complete eigenbasis, *so it's meaningful to diagonalize* $J_z$ by listing its eigenvalues. It is not obvious to me that if we allowed any kind of generators that it would be meaningful to diagonalize $J_z$; maybe our eigenvalues would only correspond to the diagonal of some triangular matrix that was not diagonal.

Comment: SU(2) is compact, and as such its unitary representations are finite-dimensional and its non-unitary ones infinite-dimensional, following general rules. Wybourne's [standard text](https://books.google.com/books/about/Classical_Groups_for_Physicists.html?id=OQGiieSztuIC) works out most. *But* this question resolutely belongs to the math SE, instead.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535927/every-irreducible-representation-of-a-compact-group-is-finite-dimensional) might be helpful, if you can read the language.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for pointing out Wybourne's text. Pages 95 and 96 directly answer my question as posed. I'll need to work a little more to understand behavior of representations of simple compact Lie groups. I'm thinking about what you said about MSE being a better place for the question. I'm probably not going to do this, but I'd understand if you voted to close -> off topic -> belongs on another stack exchange network -> MSE.